# Firestore data loads every time when moving to different view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
func loadUserThings() { 


        Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
            if let document = snapshot {
                var data = document.data()
                self.nameLabel.text = data?["username"] as? String ?? ""
                self.usernameLabel.text = data?["username"] as? String ?? ""
            }
    }

}
```

The above function is called in the viewdidLoad() of the view controller.

I am retrieving data from firebase firestore. When I move between view controllers or open the app the labels are loaded again. The data is caching as i can see it when there is no internet but even then it takes time to load.

Firestore Data Loading every time in labels

[image]

Comment: Have you debug that every time u r getting different data as I can see its loading default value which you set in your storyboard. Have you sen any static data in storyboard labels ?

Comment: Yes. I have set static data in the storyboard. It first loads storyboard values then firestore values. I even tried removing storyboard values but its doing the same thing.

Comment: Can you post code of your firestore fetching data ?

Comment: Yes @CodeChanger . I updated the question.

Comment: as its taking from server it will take some time to fetch data and for that time of period juts show `Welcome` and not to show default value from storyboard will solve your problem.

Comment: But it is happening like that even when there is no internet connection. It should load instantly when taking data from the cache.

Comment: why do you have what looks like real data as your default?  why not "... waiting for update ..." or something similar?

Comment: If all you are loading is the username & email, and if that doesn't change then load it once into VC variables, and only call Firestore if the username is blank

Comment: yes but its checking internet and that will take some time that you are now offline and need to take cache data so will take time to show data. You enabled/disabled `PersistenceEnabled` will check if its taking cache data or actually taking from firestore online.

Comment: Even if there is internet it should not load the data again. It should not be like that. @CodeChanger

Comment: so what you want here I am  now confused with your query.

Comment: Basically. Each and every time i open something the label is changed after a couple of seconds. Be it online or offline taking from cache. I don't want that delay.

Comment: So you mean to say without taking time it should show your fetched data but dear its web based data fetching from server so its totally depends on your internet speed and server speed so it will take 1 or 2 or 3 sec or more to get data from server. that is the common scenario.

Comment: But it should load instantly from the cache nah ? Bhai su waat karo cho ? @CodeChanger

Comment: And for storing data in cache at least 1st time you need to get it from server and that will take some time if you want to differentiate both call server & cache there are two method in firestore to make offline & online call from ur code. use that one and you will always get cache data if you are offline.

Comment: Okay. I’ll try that

Comment: The code used is same. No matter retrieving from cache data.

Comment: @Swapstar Where have you used the above-mentioned comment? Is it on viewWillAppear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of thing happens when you are using getData function of Firestone. 
Using a snapshot listener will remove this issue.